# Logparser Count Components

Tags: parsing, logparser

I have a daily log file that dumps out of a PLC and sample text is (it has no headers, just raw data):

```
5/29/2009 3:05:33 PM: PLC Requested Hand Scan
5/29/2009 3:05:40 PM: HH Label Data Retrieved: 078797312
5/29/2009 3:05:40 PM: PLC Requested Scale Weight
5/29/2009 3:05:40 PM: Scale Data Retrieved:    56.0
5/29/2009 3:05:40 PM: ProcessMOSData Loop: 1
5/29/2009 3:05:40 PM: About to read
5/29/2009 3:05:40 PM: Read: False
5/29/2009 3:05:40 PM: ProcessMOSData Loop: 2
5/29/2009 3:05:40 PM: About to read
5/29/2009 3:05:40 PM: Read: True
5/29/2009 3:05:40 PM: Found Bin02
5/29/2009 3:05:40 PM: ProcessMOSData Loop: 3
5/29/2009 3:05:40 PM: About to read
5/29/2009 3:05:40 PM: Read: False
5/29/2009 3:05:40 PM: ProcessMOSData Loop: 4
5/29/2009 3:05:40 PM: About to read
5/29/2009 3:05:40 PM: Read: False
5/29/2009 3:05:40 PM: ProcessMOSData Loop: 5
5/29/2009 3:05:40 PM: About to read
5/29/2009 3:05:41 PM: Read: False
5/29/2009 3:05:41 PM: ProcessMOSData Loop: 6
5/29/2009 3:05:41 PM: About to read
5/29/2009 3:05:41 PM: Read: False
5/29/2009 3:05:41 PM: ProcessMOSData Loop: 7
5/29/2009 3:05:41 PM: About to read
5/29/2009 3:05:41 PM: Read: False
5/29/2009 3:05:41 PM: ProcessMOSData Loop: 8
5/29/2009 3:05:41 PM: About to read
5/29/2009 3:05:41 PM: Read: False
5/29/2009 3:05:41 PM: ProcessMOSData Loop: 9
5/29/2009 3:05:41 PM: About to read
5/29/2009 3:05:41 PM: Read: False
5/29/2009 3:05:41 PM: Got all data
5/29/2009 3:05:41 PM: Wrote good label ack
```

I have 15 "key phrases" that I would like to count. I have 1150 text files that I would probably combine into one large text file and then after the initial read just have it read and dump into the new table. It could output to csv or sql, doesn't really matter. The final piece will just be monitoring how improvements in process changes have increased efficiency in the area.

As an example, one of the key phrases is "PLC Requested Hand Scan", so in the sample it would have 5/29/2009 1 time. I was thinking the headers at the top would be the key phrases and on the left side would be the different days. It seems like this would be something logparser could do, but without things having headers and each line just being one long string, I am not sure how to get started.

Answer (score 0):

YES, you can solve this using LogParser.
To get the right query easyly install LogParser Lizard, its a simple and free tool for you to test your queries at Logparser, before coding.

Set Logparser input to TEXTLINE input format.

At the FROM clause you can contatenate as many files as you want, like this 
FROM 'filename', 'filename2', 'filename3' and so on (all must have same structure)

Here is a logparser query that will help you to start

```
SELECT extract_token(Text,0,' ') AS Date,
       strcat(extract_token(extract_token(Text,1,' '),0,'PM: '),' PM') AS Time,
       extract_token(Text,1,'PM: ') AS MSG
FROM 'F:\test.txt'
```

Also you can group by msg doing this

```
SELECT extract_token(Text,1,'PM: ') AS MSG
FROM 'F:\test.txt'
GROUP BY MSG
```